# How did 來 ("wheat") compound with  ("left hand") to mean 差?

Tags: glyph-origin

If I translated [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B7%AE) correctly, it moots the concept of hulling wheat by rubbing grains inside hands, just as [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B7%AE#Glyph_origin) does. But this doesn't answer my question? How do 來 and  semantically appertain to 差?

My Chinese is too rudimentary to understand [Shuowen](http://www.shuowen.org/view/3013). But if Below is [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%B7%AE).

[image]

Comment: I'm not commenting on CUHK's correctness, but the complete explanation ends with `是「搓」的初文(夏淥)。`. Therefore, according to this explanation, the character is a phonetic loan, and the question (`how did...mean...`) is a wrong question. I suggest really learning how to parse Chinese correctly.

Comment: Also - I don't understand the point of pasting Yellowbridge explanations everywhere; please don't do it just so you can meet the `show prior research` criteria, the prior research is supposed to be both informative (for you) and saving time (for us, so we don't go through the same research), and Yellowbridge seems to get stuff wrong **all the time**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形｜隸定 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: ⿱木] | 官差父簋 [集成4032](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=4032&jgwfl=) |
| [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) 金 | [image: ⿱來右] | 敔王夫差劍 [集成11637](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=11637&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) 金 | [image: ⿱來右] | 楚王酓忓鼎 [集成2794](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=2794&jgwfl=) |
| 戰國・楚 [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: ⿱來左] | 120 曾侯乙墓簡 |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image] | [左部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=27) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 差] | 嘉祥畫象石 |

<kbd>[image: ⿱木]</kbd>

「差」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*tsʰraj/**, Mandarin Pinyin: **chāi**) originally depicted a [*left hand* 「」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=19787) picking out an object, here a [*tree* 「木」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=139), indicating the meaning *to select, to choose*, e.g. between objects of a better or worse quality. From the *[Classic of Poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Poetry): Lesser Court Hymns: Lucky Day*:

> ##### 《詩經・小雅・吉日》
>
> 吉日庚午、既**差我馬**。
> 獸之所同、麀鹿麌麌。
> 漆沮之從、天子之所。
>
> *A lucky day was [gēng-wǔ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%9A%E5%8D%88#Chinese). We had **selected our horses**;* 
> *The haunts of the animals, where the does* and stags lay numerous,* 
> *The grounds by the Qī and the Jū - that was the place for the [son of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Heaven) [to hunt].*
>      <sub>—— Translation by [James Legge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Legge). See [ctext.org](https://ctext.org/book-of-poetry/ji-ri).</sub>
>
> <sub>Reading caution: *does* is the plural of *doe*, a female deer.</sub>

*To choose [between objects of a different quality]* was then semantically extended to mean *difference*, then *bad, incorrect*.

<kbd>[image: ⿱來右]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: ⿱來右]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: ⿱來左]</kbd>

「木」 was later graphically corrupted into [「來」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=742), and *left hand* 「」 was often replaced with *right* [「右」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=201) or *left* [「左」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=230). 「左」 (**/*tsˤa[j]ʔ/**) survives in the modern form due to its ability to double as a sound hint.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 差]</kbd>

「來」 was later further graphically corrupted into [「」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=19970), then again corrupted into 「」, forming the modern 「差」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 《王力古漢語字典》
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/zh)

  - [*Classic of Poetry: Lesser Court Hymns: Lucky Day*](https://ctext.org/book-of-poetry/ji-ri)
- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)